# Валидация множества input

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

Код html:

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1 class="logo">todoosh</h1>
        <input type="text" id="inp" autocomplete="off">
        <div class="field">
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="./js/index.js"></script>
</body>
```

Код css:

```
.complete{
    text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

Код js:

```
function addTask(inputText) {
    var field = document.querySelector('.field'),
        task = document.createElement('div'),
        elemTxt = document.createTextNode(inputText),
        completeCheckBox = document.createElement('input');

    completeCheckBox.type = 'checkbox';
    completeCheckBox.id = 'complete-checkbox';

    // taskComplete();
    task.className = 'task';
    completeCheckBox.addEventListener('click', () => {
        let chbox = document.getElementById('complete-checkbox');
        if (chbox.checked) {
            task.classList.add('complete');
        } else {
            task.classList.remove('complete');
        }
    })
    task.append(completeCheckBox);
    task.append(elemTxt);
    field.prepend(task);
}
```

[image: Скриншот]

Текст в поле с отмеченным чекбоксе должен зачеркиваться, когда чекбокс не отмечен - текст в поле не зачеркнут.
В коде приведенном выше работает только наивысшее поле.

Comment: id элемента должен быть уникальным если что =)

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков, это исправит проблему?

Comment: А вы попробуйте перед тем как задавать такие вопросы =) Ну а коли хочется теории то вот:
https://yadi.sk/i/4MPiZrHQoM-f2Q    https://yadi.sk/i/hwiAk75N5CDPog

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков, я попробовал до вашего комента - не помогло. За теорию огромное спасибо, 1е это learn.js, а 2е?

Comment: Понятия не имею, что попалось в гугле то и заскринил =)

Answer (score 2):

Гошподя, зачем весь этот геморрой?

```css
input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<input id="a1" type="checkbox" />
<label for="a1">Text 1</label><br>


<input id="a2" type="checkbox" />
<label for="a2">Text 2</label>
```

Всё.